# What's the meaning of these lines of code from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, variables

I'm trying to explain a batch file I've written for work and I'm having a hard time explaining this one section.  To be clear, the section works as designed so this is not a question about how to write it; I just can't figure out what it's called and how to explain it to a coworker.  In particular, I'm curious about the bit with the **tilde**.  For instance, **:~0,1** in my bit of code and **:~0,3** and **:~3,2**.  For the life of me, I cannot explain how they work.  I think they *expand* the variable but that's only what can come up with from Googling.

This is the section from my script:

```
:_RebootQuestion
ECHO.
Set /p _Resp=Would you like to reboot now (Y/N)?
If /I "%_Resp:~0,1%"=="Y" shutdown -r -t 0 -f
If /I "%_Resp:~0,1%"=="N" exit
If /I NOT "%_Resp:~0,1%"=="N" (
    Echo Y or N please. &GoTo _RebootQuestion
    )
```

This is an example I've seen out on the web:

```
set test=12345 
echo %test:~0,3% 
echo %test:~3,2%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called substrings. Basically they extract part of a variable specified by the `character length` and `offset`.
 In you script, `%_Resp:~0,1%` is taking the first character of the users input and checking whether it is *Y* or *N*. 
This means the user can enter *Yes, No, Y, N* as they all begin with the same letter

As documented by `set /?`

> May also specify substrings for an expansion.
>
> ```
> %PATH:~10,5%
> ```
>
> would expand the PATH environment variable, and then use only the 5
>   characters that begin at the 11th (offset 10) character of the
>   expanded result.  If the length is not specified, then it defaults to
>   the remainder of the variable value.  If either number (offset or
>   length) is negative, then the number used is the length of the
>   environment variable value added to the offset or length specified.
>
> ```
> %PATH:~-10%
> ```
>
> would extract the last 10 characters of the PATH variable.
>
> ```
> %PATH:~0,-2%
> ```
>
> would extract all but the last 2 characters of the PATH variable.

Comment: Okay, good find!  I had looked up help with **FOR** and **IF** but I forgot to look up **SET**.

Comment: I guess I cannot mark both as the answer.  You both gave great/helpful answers.  Both allowed me to understand what was going on.

Comment: @RKillcrazy, well if you ask me this is the correct answer as it using the actual documentation from the SET help file that you can view from the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1):

See https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html.
Basically, you are extracting a substring of the variable:

```
  %variable:~num_chars_to_skip%
  %variable:~num_chars_to_skip,num_chars_to_keep%
```